# How to find a number from each line of a text file

Tags: c

How to find a number from each line of a text file?
For exemple in file is written:

Apple 500 America

Motorola 400 China

How i can find in a text file the int number (price)and to established if it is bigger than 450?

Comment: You'll need to provide actual code that you've tried.  Stack overflow isn't here for people to write your code for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  If you do not provide an actual attempt at code and specify what isn't working, your question will likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Which textbook are you using?

Comment: I use notepad for a text input

Answer (score 1):

Given the format of the text file remains the same for all lines, you may use a combination of `strtok` and `atoi` to extract the number in between. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] = "Apple 500 America";
    char *pch;

    pch = strtok (str," \t\n");     // ignore 1st string
    pch = strtok (NULL, " \t\n");   // get 2nd string
    int i = atoi( pch );            // parse 2nd string to int
    printf( "i = %d\n", i );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`i = 500`